# Aligning Cards On Top Of One Another Smaller Screens With Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I have a row of several cards of different sizes. On larger screens it looks fine, like so:

[image: layout looks good]

but on smaller widths, the cards don't look great.

[image]

I would like to stack the cards, so that the key stats on the right are aligned underneath the Quant ratings on the left hand side.

Here is the website:  https://cs50-final-stock.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured this out.  I leveraged the Bootstrap Docs to determine the proper classes for stacking on smaller screens. The key is adding sm to all of the col tags.

More info here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/layout/grid/#stacked-to-horizontal